# "Footbridge" and "overhead bridge"

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between "footbridge" and "overhead bridge"? Which term is more suitable to describe a bridge for pedestrians crossing above a roadway? Thank you in advance for your advice!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Street_Overhead_Bridge) has, for instance, the brief article:  << King Street Overhead Bridge is a historic overhead bridge located at Kings Mountain, Cleveland County, North Carolina. It was built in 1938–1939, and is a reinforced concrete Moderne-style rigid-frame vehicular bridge. It measures about 48 feet long and 49 feet wide and carries West King Street over the Norfolk Southern Railway railroad tracks.>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "overhead bridge" is a bridge that's overhead (and the term is usually used to express it's relationship to other passageways, especially train tracks).

A "footbridge" is a bridge that's used primarily for foot traffic (pedestrians).

These are really no different from "green bridge" or "steel bridge" -- they're just "bridge" with a descriptive term.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should stick to "footbridge" as the bridge I am referring to is for pedestrians only. Where I live (Singapore), people tend to use the word "overhead bridge" more often.

Answer (score 1):

While both terms may be applicable, you have to consider what's more important. It's always a footbridge, but whether it's an overhead bridge depends on where you are.

In the context of a discussion of the road it crosses, you may even consider *overhead footbridge* though that's unlikely to be necessary, as you could assume the bridge goes over the road (it can't be part of the road because it's a footbridge).

Answer (score 1):

"Overhead" relates to the location of the bridge.  A bridge over water would not, for example, be an overhead bridge.

"Footbridge" relates to the kind of traffic permitted on the bridge or suitable for it.  A bridge over water might be for people, vehicles, cattle, bikes.

It seems to be a bridge could even be an underground bridge, going below the roadway--so that pedestrians and bikes and get across without stopping traffic.  What would you call a path for pedestrians that goes beneath the road, the road being overhead?  Sometimes it might be called a below-surface bridge.  It does, after all, bridge the two sides.

Comment: The underground one wouldn’t be a bridge for me, it’d be an underpass. YMMV

Comment: In BrE Civil Engineering jargon we have overbridges and underbridges, where an overbridge carries other traffic over whatever reference you're using, and an underbridge carries it under your reference. Hence for a bridge carrying rail over a road, a highway engineer will call it an overbridge and a rail engineer will call it an underbridge.